# Jsoup post, selecting different options

Tags: scala, selenium, jsoup

http://www.myprotein.com/sports-nutrition/impact-whey-protein/10530943.html

I would like retrieve the prices for the different amounts, i.e. 1kg and 2.5kg

The first option is quite straightforward.

```
val page = Jsoup.connect("http://www.myprotein.com/sports-nutrition/impact-whey-protein/10530943.html").get()
println(page.select("div.media").select("h2.price").text.replaceAll("[a-zA-z\\s]", ""))
```

Getting the different options:

```
    for (value <- page.getElementById("opts-7").getElementsByAttribute("value").asScala ) {
  println(value.attr("value"))
}
```

However I have no idea about how to go on with the post, setting the cookies, headers etc. I prefer the speed and parsing abilities from Jsoup, however I am also considering taking the easy way out and using selenium to select the other options and parsing the source with jsoup.

So I decided to change to Selenium. It's selecting the right option with an emulated click however the price isn't updating. If I avoid closing the WebDriver and select the 2.5 kg manually it updates price accordingly

```
var driver: WebDriver = null
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    setupWebDriver()
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.myprotein.com/sports-nutrition/impact-whey-protein/10530943.html")
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"opts-7\"]/option[2]")).click()
    val temp = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource)
    println(temp.select("div.product-price").text())}
```

There's the main method and the WebDriver setup

```
   def setupWebDriver() {
       val binaryExe = "\\phantomjs.exe"
       val BinaryChrome = "\\chromedriver.exe"
       val caps: DesiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities()
       caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, System.getProperty("user.dir") + binaryExe)
       System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", System.getProperty("user.dir") + binaryExe)
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + BinaryChrome)
       caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true)
       caps.setBrowserName(BrowserType.GOOGLECHROME)
       driver = new ChromeDriver(caps)
       driver.manage.timeouts.implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)}
```

Can anyone enlighten me on how I would get the price to update this way?

Comment: In this case, the price seems to be calculated by JavaScript when you select something from the dropdowns. Jsoup cannot do JavaScript, so you might need to figure out how the website gets those values. Setting cookies, headers, etc. is quite easy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however it's a form submit. If the amount is changed to 2.5kg you'll get a POST with this content: selected=3&variation1=5&option1=20619&variation2=6&option2=2407&variation3=7&option3=5913 So I thought I'd be able to get them with a simple POST

Comment: Then you have to do a similar post with Jsoup and parse the results somehow.

Comment: Yes but I have no idea how to start about it.

Comment: You have to get started by finding out what you actually need to download, and from where. Most web browsers have development console, where you can see what network requests are being sent. Try using that see what happens when you click the button, and then try to emulate that with jsoup. It seems that in this case the request is done with ajax, and the script downloads the price information when the button is clicked, no post needed.